# How can I hide image (tree for example) in progressbar theme of beamer

Tags: beamer

How can I hide the image (tree for example) in progressbar theme of `beamer`?
I would like to change the color of title of section too.

Is it possible?

MWE

```
\documentclass[compress, 14pt]{beamer}

\usetheme{progressbar}
\progressbaroptions{headline=normal}

\begin{document}

\section{First}
\begin{frame}{Title}
Content
\end{frame}

\section{Second}*\color{yellow} here for example
\begin{frame}{\color{yellow}Teste 1}
Content
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: MWE is not working for me, the theme's .sty file can not be found.

Comment: The progressbar theme comes from http://recherche.noiraudes.net/fr/LaTeX.php.

Comment: elemakil (I'm sorry by my poor English ok!) you need to go to (in your comp) start/miktex 2.9/maintenance (admin)/package maintenance(admin) and then choosing the package and installing it. After this, start/miktex 2.9/maintenance (admin)/settings (admin) refresh fndb and update formats

Comment: @Moura Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

The progress bar itself is defined in the outer theme, so you could use just use `\useoutertheme{progressbar}` in combination with any other general theme. Similarly, you could select any color theme with `\usecolortheme`, or define specific colors using `\setbeamercolor`. For example:

```
\documentclass[compress, 14pt]{beamer}
\usetheme{Dresden}
\useoutertheme{progressbar}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=yellow}

\begin{document}

\section{First}
\begin{frame}{Title}
Content
\end{frame}

\section{Second}
\begin{frame}{Test 1}
Content
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```